# what is the correct way to change the app status bar white and status bar black in color in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, background-color, android-statusbar

Change my app status bar color to white and status bar icon color to black

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Since, setSystemUiVisibility() is Deprecated and my minSdk version is 21 and targetSdk version is 31

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change the status bar color using the **Window** class added in `API level 21`

```
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.my_statusbar_color))
```

Comment: And how to change the status bar icon color to black

Comment: window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: Both are same item it only changes status bar color not status bar icon color

Comment: but your question says about color not icon

Comment: questions says both status bar color and status bar icon color

Comment: ok , can you show with an image what you want?

Comment: I want to change the status bar icon color to black and status bar color to white